# Can not resolve symbol REQUEST_CODE

Tags: java, android

I am trying to select an image from gallery using this code placed in my UploadActivity class

```
     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
private void selectImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null ){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
            ImageHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But it keep giving me the above error. Is there what I need to import and if yes what is it because the IDE - android studio does not show me when I click on options.
If there is nothing to be imported, what can I edit to solve the error?

I'll appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear. The variable REQUEST_CODE has not been declared yet.
Simply declare it as private and initialize it to 1 like this:

```
    private int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

I hope that works

Answer (score 3):

Just define a constant value holding your request code. 
Like so `private static final Int REQUEST_CODE = 12`

The value of the `REQUEST_CODE` can be any number, but it should be unique in the sense that if your `onActivityResult` gets called by different sources, each of those sources **must** have a different request code. Otherwise you will end up in the wrong condition.